# After ajax call, new 'onclick' handlers don't work until a click somewhere on the page

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

I have an issue after returning from an jQuery `get()` ajax call.  The response populates a div with additional div's.  These new div's contain `onclick` event handlers.  The browser is needing a click anywhere on the page before I can click on the newly populated div and get it's `onclick` to fire.

**EDIT** Resolved by removing `return false` from `ajaxSearch` and `event.preventdefault()` from `keypress`.

**Here's the specifics of what is happening:**

1. Enter a value in the `srchKey` textbox, press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
2. The `ajaxSearch` function fires and gets data.
3. The `displayResults` function successfully updates the `searchResults` div and up to 10 div's are stacked vertically on the left.  Each of the new `searchResult` div's has an `onclick='resultClick(this, '/Path...', displayRecord)` set on it where the `/Path...` varies according to the data.
4. **I am forced to click somewhere on the page (doesn't matter where) before the `onclick` will fire.**
5. After the first click, I can click again on one of the `searchResult` div's and the `onclick` script is called.

*To the user it appears that the first time you click on one of the `searchResult` div's, nothing happens.  After you have clicked once, then each subsequent click on one of the `searchResult` div's works as expected.*

The issue appears to be browser independent (at least to the extent that it does the same thing in Chrome and Firefox).

I'm using the following jQuery script in my page:

```
function displayResults(data) {
    $('.searchResults').html(data);
    return false;
}

function resultClick(selected, req, callback) {
    $('.searchResult').removeClass('selected');
    $(selected).addClass('selected');
    $.get(req, callback);
    return false;
}

function displayRecord(data) {
    $('#selectedRecord').html(data);
    return false;
}

function ajaxSearch() {
    $('#selectedRecord').empty();
    var myForm = $('#searchForm');
    $.post(myForm.URL, myForm.serialize(), displayResults);
    return false;
}

$(function () {
    $('#loadingDiv').hide();

    $('.watched').blur(ajaxSearch);
    $('#srchDate').blur(ajaxSearch);

    $(document).keypress(function (event) {
        if (event.which === 13) {
            event.preventDefault();
            ajaxSearch();
        }
    });
});
```

My razor page looks like:

```
...

<div id="searchPage">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index","Controller",FormMethod.Post, new {id="searchForm"}))
    {
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Criteria</legend>
            <div class="search" id="srchKey">
                 @Html.LabelFor(m=>m.Key)
                 @Html.EditorFor(m=>m.Key)
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    }
    <div class="resultsBlock">
        <div class="searchResults" id="unitResults"></div>
        <div id="selectedRecord"></div>
    </div>
</div>

@section scripts
{
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/search.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open firebug and switch to the net tab, you then will see if the first click is working. You can also try manually add a &lgt;div onclick='resultClick(this, '/Path...', displayRecord)' to see if it works.

Also, you can see if there is any js error in firebug.

Comment: The first click is not working.  I have to click somewhere, anywhere, on the page before the 'onclick' event will fire.  I know that the 'onclick' is firing successfully, but the behavior is like when another window is active, and you have to click on the window that you want to be active before you can then work in it.

Comment: even clicking on the window border?

Comment: ah ha!  Looking at the net tab, showed me that the 'first' click is actually doing a post again through the 'ajaxSearch'. **That led me to understanding that the 'return false' in 'ajaxSearch' and 'event.preventdefault' in the 'keypress' were causing this behavior.  ** Thanks for the help!